# error when trying to run my tensorflow code

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

This is a follow up question from my latest post: [Put input in a tensorflow neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759790/put-input-in-a-tensorflow-neural-network)

I precoded a neural network using tensorflow with the MNIST dataset, and with the help of @FinnE was able to change a bit of my code, the two files are listed below:

main.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mnist=tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train=tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test=tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(val_loss, val_acc)

model.save("num_reader.model")
new_model=tf.keras.models.load_model('num_reader.model')
predictions=new_model.predict([x_test])
print(predictions)
```

screen.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pygame
import sys
import numpy as np
from main import *
import main as nn

class Screen:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        #self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((28,28),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((280,280))
        self.array=[]
        self.setArr()
        self.bg_color=(250, 250,250)
        self.ok=False
        self.full=[]
        self.done=False
        print(new_model)
        self.result=0

    def runGame(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        while True:
            pygame.display.flip()
            self._check_events()
            self.draw()
            if self.full != []:
                break

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
                if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                    self.done=True
                    self.decode()
                    print(len(self.full))
                if event.key==pygame.K_c:
                    self.done=False
                    self.setArr()
                    self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #print("mouseDown")
                self.ok=True
            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.ok=False

    def setArr(self):
        self.shortArr=[]
        for y in range(28):
            self.shortArr.append(0)
        for x in range(28):
            self.array.append(self.shortArr)

    def draw(self):
        if self.ok==True:
            x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x=round(x/10)*10
            y=round(y/10)*10

            #print(x,y)
            #print(self.array[int(x)//10][int(y)//10])
            self.array[int(x)//10][int(y)//10]=1

            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 10))
            #print("draw")

    def decode(self):
        self.full=[]
        for x in range(28):
            for y in range(28):
                self.full.append(self.array[x][y])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sc=Screen()
    Sc.runGame()
    result = nn.new_model.predict(tf.keras.utils.normalize(np.array(Sc.full), axis=1))
    print(result)
```

however I get the following error when the code is run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Jake\machine learning\MNIST dataset SOLVED\screen.py", line 81, in <module>
    result = nn.new_model.predict(tf.keras.utils.normalize(np.array(Sc.full), axis=1))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 89, in normalize
    l2 = np.atleast_1d(np.linalg.norm(x, order, axis))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in norm
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2547, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: Writing `@FinnE` in your post won't ping that user. If you want them to take a look, I recommend leaving a comment on their answer to your old post that includes a link to this one.

Comment: Can you print `np.array(Sc.full).shape`? It probably won't have a second dimension, so normalizing against axis 1 won't work.

Comment: @ClaudiaR when printed it gives me the response " (784,) "

Comment: You don't have an axis 1. 1D arrays just have axis 0 (or -1 if you want to always refer to the last axis)

Comment: @Djinn what should I do?

Comment: your code trains model at every start of `screen.py` because it imports `main`. You could run `main.py` only once - to create and save model. And in `screen.py` you could run directly `load_model` without importing `main` - and it may run faster because it doesn't have to train model again.

Comment: maybe split code in line `result = nn.new_model.predict(...)` to separated lines and add `print()` to see whant you get in variables in every step - `print(Sc.full)`. `print(np.array(Sc.full))`, etc. this way you can see what you really have in variables and which step can make problem.

Comment: error shows problem with `axis=1`, and it shows also line `nn.new_model.predict(..., axis=1)`  - so maybe you should change this `axis=1` to smaller.

Comment: `setArr` is wrong. You append the same `short_arr` - so next you will have the same values in all rows. You have to nested `for`-loops and always create new `short_arr` for new row.

Comment: it seems PyGame sometimes may gives `y = 280` and next `int(y)//10` gives `28` but array has only `0...27` and it raise error.

Comment: I think there is another common problem. Your array keeps data as `x,y` but `numpy` (and all matrixes in math) keeps as `y,x` (`row, column`) - so tensorflow may get rotated image and it may not recognize it.

Comment: I get another problem - you send flat list with 768 values (28x28)to `predict()` but it seems it needs 2D array `28x28`

Comment: another problem: code uses array with shape `(28,28)` but predict needs `(1,28,28)` - so it has  use `[self.array]` instead of `self.array` in `np.array()`

Answer (score 1):

There is few problems.

1. you return flat array with 786 values but it needs 2D array 28x28 - and this makes problem with `axis=1` in `normalize` - you have to use `self.array` instead of `self.full`
2. you create array `28x28` but predict needs `1x28x28` - so it needs `[self.array]` instead of `self.array

```
result = nn.new_model.predict(tf.keras.utils.normalize(np.array([Sc.array]), axis=1))
```

3. it returns probability for all digits and you have to use `np.argmax()` to get digit with the biggest probability. Because `predict()` can get list with many images so it returns list with many results - even if you check single image - and it needs `[0]` to check result for first image.

```
digit = np.argmax(result[0])
```

4. I think there is problem with data in array. You keep it as `x,y` but `numpy`  uses `y,x` (`row, column`) (and the same is with matrix in math). It needs `self.array[y][x] = 1` instea `self.array[x][y] = 1`. **EDIT:** I added `plt.imshow()`, `cv2.imshow()` to confirm it. Using `x,y` it gives rotated image.
5. you import `main` and this runs all code in `main` and it trains model again at every start. You don't have to import `main` but only use `load_model()`.
6. on my computer sometimes `mouse.get_pos()` gives value `280` and this gives `array[...][28]`, and this raises error because array has only `[27]`. It needs to check `x`, `y` and convert `280` to `279` (or later convert `28` to `27`)
7. you `setArr()` is wrong. You append the same list `self.shortArr` to `self.array` but (this is popular problem in Python) it doesn't put copy of array but it puts reference to the same array - and finally when you change one value in row then it change them in all rows.

**EDIT:**

8. `mnist` has images which use values `0...255` so maybe you should also use `self.array[y][x] = 255` instead of `self.array[y][x] = 1`

---

My full working code:

`screen.py`

**EDIT:** I added right mouse to clear single pixel(s)

**EDIT:** I added `plt.imshow()`, `cv2.imshow()`

```
import pygame
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Screen:
    
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((28,28),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((280,280))
        self.bg_color = (250, 250,250)
        
        self.array = []
        self.set_arr()

        self.ok = False    # exit with prediction
        self.done = False
        #self.button = False

    def run(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        while not self.done:
            pygame.display.flip()
            self._check_events()
            self.draw()
        pygame.quit()  # some systems need it to close window
        return self.ok
    
    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # end program without OK
                self.done = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    # end program without OK
                    self.done = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    # end program with OK
                    self.ok = True
                    self.done = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    # clear array and screen
                    self.set_arr()
                    self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            #if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #    #print("mouseDown")
            #    self.button = True
            #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            #    self.button = False

    def set_arr(self):
        """Create empty array 2D for image."""
        self.array = [[0 for x in range(28)] for y in range(28)]

    def draw(self):
        buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if buttons[0] or buttons[2]:  # left or right button
        #if self.button:
            x0, y0 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
            if x0 >= 280:
                x0 = 279
            if y0 >= 280:
                y0 = 279
                
            x = int(round(x0/10)*10)
            y = int(round(y0/10)*10)

            try:
                #self.array[int(x)//10][int(y)//10] = 255
                if buttons[0]:  # left draw
                    self.array[int(y)//10][int(x)//10] = 255
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 10))
                if buttons[2]:  # right clear
                    self.array[int(y)//10][int(x)//10] = 0                
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 10))
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Exception:', ex)
                print('Debug:', x0, y0, x, y, int(x)//10, int(y)//10)

            #print("draw")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('loading model ...')
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('num_reader.model')

    print('starting screen')
    screen = Screen()
    ok = screen.run()
    
    if not ok:
        print('finish without prediction')
    else:
        image = np.array(screen.array, dtype='uint8')
        print('image.shape:', image.shape)
        
        print('--- show image ---')
        
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))        
        plt.show()
        
        #import cv2
        #cv2.imshow('image', image)        
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
        
        print('--- predict as is ---')
        
        arr = np.array([image])
        print('arr.shape:', arr.shape)
        #print(arr[:,:2])
        results = model.predict(arr)
        print('results:', results)
        digit = np.argmax(results[0])
        print('digit:', digit)

        print('--- predict normalized ---')

        arr = tf.keras.utils.normalize(np.array([image]), axis=1)
        print('arr.shape:', arr.shape)
        #print(arr[:,:2])
        results = model.predict(arr)
        print('results:', results)
        digit = np.argmax(results[0])
        print('digit:', digit)
```

`train_model.py`

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('val_loss:', val_loss)
print('val_acc :', val_acc)

#predictions = model.predict([x_test])
#print(predictions)

model.save("num_reader.model")
```